# How to read output of sed into a variable

Tags: shell, variables, sed

I have variable which has value `"abcd.txt"`.

I want to store everything before the `".txt"` in a second variable, replacing the `".txt"` with `".log"`

I have no problem echoing the desired value:

```
a="abcd.txt"

echo $a | sed 's/.txt/.log/'
```

But how do I get the value `"abcd.log"` into the second variable?

Answer (score 104):

You can use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) as:

```
new_filename=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/.txt/.log/')
```

or the less recommended backtick way:

```
new_filename=`echo "$a" | sed 's/.txt/.log/'`
```

Comment: even better: `new_filename="$(echo "$a" | sed 's/.txt/.log/')"` (in Bash pairs of `" "` inside command substitution still match).

Comment: "Less recommended"? Maybe for bash, but the shell hasn't been specified, so it may be the only option :-)

Answer (score 21):

You can use backticks to assign the output of a command to a variable:

```
logfile=`echo $a | sed 's/.txt/.log/'`
```

That's assuming you're using Bash.

Alternatively, for this particular problem Bash has pattern matching constructs itself:

```
stem=$(textfile%%.txt)
logfile=$(stem).log
```

or

```
logfile=$(textfile/%.txt/.log)
```

The % in the last example will ensure only the last .txt is replaced.

Comment: As I understand it, you are supposed to use *Bash Command Substitution*, not back ticks. Also see [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/56041), [Command substitution with string substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30146466/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is

```
logfile="${a/\.txt/\.log}"
```

If it should be allowed that the filename in `$a` has more than one occurrence of `.txt` in it, use the following solution. Its more safe. It only changes the last occurrence of `.txt`

```
logfile="${a%%\.txt}.log"
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have Bash/ksh

```
$ var="abcd.txt"
$ echo ${var%.txt}.log
abcd.log
$ variable=${var%.txt}.log
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not get me anywhere...
I was already able to echo...the problem is I want to get it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the sed expression within the `` symbol (the symbol below Escape key)

Eg :

```
FILE_NAME=`echo $a | sed 's/.txt/.log/'`
```