# Command substitution with string substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
echo ${$(ls)/foo/bar}
```

I'm pretty sure i saw somewhere working example of something like that but this results in "bad substitution" error.

I know that there are other methods to do that but such a short oneliner would be useful. Am I missing something or is this impossible?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Syntax `${...}`** only allows **referencing a *variable* (or positional parameter), optionally combined with [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)**.

**Syntax `$(...)`** (or, less preferably, its old-style equivalent, `` `...` ``), performs **[command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)**, which **allows embedding arbitrary commands** to whose **stdout output** the expression **expands**.

Thus, you could *combine* the two features as follows:

```
echo "$(lsOutput=$(ls); echo "${lsOutput//foo/bar}")"
```

<sup>Note the uncomplicated *nested* use of `$(...)`, which is one of the main advantages over `` `...` ``, whose use would require escaping here.</sup>

That said, any variables you define inside the command substitution are confined to the **subshell** that the command runs in anyway, so **you could make do with just a command that produces the desired *output***, given that it is only the stdout output that matters.

```
echo "$(ls | sed 's/foo/bar/')"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pipe `|` with `sed`, example:

```
$ echo ABC | sed 's/B/_/'
A_C
```

Or variable substitution, all explained [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), and especially at "Variable expansion / Substring replacement" section, and below an example from me:

```
$ var=ABC
$ echo ${var//B/_}
A_C
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
root@localhost:~# echo `pwd`_whatever_suffix
/root_whatever_suffix
```