# bash: inline substring selection with result of command

Tags: bash, substring

Currently I have this two commands separeted by `;`:

```
ID=$(wmctrl -d | grep "\* DG"); kdialog --msgbox "D = ${ID:(-1)}"
```

Is there away to circumvent the creation of the auxiliary variable `ID` but still use substring indexing (here used with negative index to count from behind)?

I am looking for some replacement for `XXX` in `"D = ${XXX:(-1)}"`. My current attempts all lead to "bad substitution" error.

**Note**: The original command (below) had some flaws to which some of the comments refer:

```
export ID=$(wmctrl -d | egrep "\* DG"); kdialog --msgbox "D = ${ID:(-1)}"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146466/command-substitution-with-string-substitution

Comment: No, but you don't need to export the variable.

Comment: The regex would work fine with basic `grep` also. We would replace `egrep` with `grep -E` these days, but the `-E` option is completely superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious workaround is to use `sed` instead of `egrep`:

```
kdialog --msgbox "D = $(wmctrl -d | sed -n 's/.*\* DG.*\(.\)$/\1/p')"
```

The logic here is to not print any lines by default (`-n`); then on the line matching the regex, substitute the entire line with just its last character, and print when there was a match and subsequent substitution (`/p`).